# Finding inverse function for g

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

A function $g$ is given by $g(x) = x + f(x)$ , where $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ and $g:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,2]$ and $f(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{3^n}) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_n}{2^n}$ . How to actually find the inverse function of $g$ from this form , provided it's inverse exists.

Comment: In general, algebraically you won't.

Comment: what if $x$ is actually the same value as $f(x)$ in base 10 ? In fact , $f$ is just a function that converts $x$ in ternary expansion to binary expansion.

Comment: @LingMinHao then you should rewrite the question to include this

Comment: @CalvinKhor I have edited it. Is it just $g^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ in base 10 ?

Comment: Then $f(x)=x$ because it's the same number just written in different bases.

Comment: @kingW3 so is $g^{-1}(x) = \frac{x}{2}$ the correct inverse ?

Comment: Yeah the inverse of 2x is x/2.

Comment: but then is $x$ in ternary or binary form ?

Comment: There is a huge difference between the function that takes $x$, which is equal to $x$ no matter what base you use, and returns $x$, in whatever base....with the function that takes $x$ and returns its binary or ternary expansion as a **sequence**. There is another function that takes a sequence of numbers in $\{0,1\}$ that interprets it as a number  $x\in [0,1]$, and returns the sequence of elements of $\{0,1,2\}$ that would be the ternary expansion of $2x$.

Comment: In other words. As written, $g(x)=2x$. But you may instead be interested in $x\mapsto (a_1,a_2,\dots )$, or $(a_1,a_2,\dots) \mapsto (b_1,b_2,\dots)$, and its inverse.